# display a link from another php page without page reload

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

So basically I have a link as a `div` in page 1.

```
<a href="/computing/abc/page2.php" class="topic-list-item">

    <h3 class="topic-title">Internet Protocol Basics</h3>

    <div class="topic-description-text">
        Learn how Internet Protocol is used 
    </div>
</a>
```

When I click on the `div` it opens the page 2 by reloading the page.

I want the new content of page 2 to appear without any reloading while at the same time this changes my URL.

Is this possible?

Comment: You will need to use ajax calls, and modify the current url

Comment: @EoiFirst can you please give me an example

Comment: You can't change the URL without a reload

Comment: You can: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33496555/display-a-link-from-another-php-page-without-page-reload#answer-33497371

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

Disable your `<a>` tag because you will send an ajax request instead of loading a new page

```
<a href="#" data-url="/computing/abc/page2.php" class="topic-list-item">

    <h3 class="topic-title">Internet Protocol Basics</h3>

    <div class="topic-description-text">
        Learn how Internet Protocol is used 
    </div>
</a>
```

JS (jQuery):

Bind the click event to execute your ajax call, then set the HTML your server send back where you want it to be.

```
  $("a").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: $(this).data("url"),
      method: 'get',
      success: function(data){
         $("#targetContainer").html(data);
      }
    })
  });
```

The `success` function's argument will be what your server send back, the `/computing/abc/page2.php` page. You can set it where you need it to be on your page (here inside `$("#targetContainer")` ).

See [Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page) for the url modification without reload

Comment: Can you please clarify on #thePlaceWhereYouWantToPutTheNewHTML. Also, i have about 10 such div, that mean i will have 10 ajax call?
I did try the pushState but it doesn't suit my purpose.

Comment: I edited my answer. By setting `data-url` on your `<a>` tag, you can make ajax calls by using this url and avoid multiplyng code

Comment: I was wrong - it does not work, i want to change the full html not just a single div.

Comment: Then you just have to modify the `<body>` tag. If you want to change all the page maybe you could considere reloading the page ?